# Automating labels with numbers

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcmap, arcgis-10.2

Is there a way to strip characters from a string using python?
The string is varied in length...

Examples of strings:
Interstate 10
Auxiliary road 24
State highway 14

I am looking for just the numbers.
10
24
14

I am attempting to automate labeling roads by populating symbols with the numbers stripped from the strings.

The info I am working with is in an attribute table
I am using ArcMap 10.2.

I am new to python and very interested to learn if this sort of functionality is available.

Comment: Definitely.  Here's a stackoverflow question about doing just that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249388/how-do-we-remove-all-non-numeric-characters-from-a-string-in-python -- I don't currently have a current enough version of arcgis to help with building a python label expression to do it but it should be possible in versions 10.1 and newer.

Comment: And the help from 10.2 about building label expressions that I forgot to add: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s800000027000000

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The link offered by Kevin does the job but it won't clean the extra spaces.
Use this python expression:

```
import re
inputText = "12 Interstate 10 Auxiliary road 24 Sta1te highway 14"
t = re.sub("[^0-9 ]", "", inputText)
resultText = ' '.join(t.split())
```

it outputs:
'12 10 24 1 14'

To use this simple script with ArcGIS lable expression, see the snapshot:

[image: label expression remove non-numeric characters]

Comment: Can you import modules in a label expression?

Comment: Yes you can, importing textwrap in label expressions works.

Comment: Thanks so much for the prompt responses. My map roads labeled like a dream. I can't wait to share this with my class mates and teacher.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a RegX, another option you could use would just be a single line using the string join and isdigit() test.

```
"".join(c for c in [NAME] if c.isdigit())
```

I just tried that for my roads layer (make sure the parser is set to Python) in ArcGIS Desktop 10.1 and it pulled out the road numbers very nicely.  Only thing to note, non-numeric roads will go unlabeled that way, so, you may have to set up label classes to label numeric roads and named roads differently.

Obviously in the code above, replace [NAME] with your appropriate field name.